# How to change img src from when click

Tags: jquery

How to change the IMG SRC name  When click the element of data-src ?

My DOM looks like as follow :

```
<div class="img"><img src="../../images/img_apple.png" alt=""></div>

<ul class="list"> 
    <li data-src="img_apple"><a href="#">img 1</a></li>
    <li data-src="img_orange"><a href="#">img 2</a></li>
    <li data-src="img_melon"><a href="#">img 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these codes by jquery:

```
$('ul.list li').each(function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var src = _this.data("src");
  _this.find('a').click(function(){
    $(".img img").attr("src", src)
 })
})
```